# CSS Specificity about MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to build WordPress plugin admin manager screen by MUI, but I find a problem about CSS specificity.
Here it is normal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TplZJ.png)

But the fact is that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51L6y.png)

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import StyledEngineProvider from "@mui/material/StyledEngineProvider";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('wpbody'));
root.render(
    <Paper sx={{padding: 3}}>
        <Typography sx={{padding: 1}}>基础设置</Typography>
        <FormGroup sx={{maxWidth: 300}}>
            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="App ID" variant={"filled"} sx={{margin: 1}}/>
            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="App Secret" variant={"filled"} sx={{margin: 1}}/>
            <Box>
                <Button variant={"contained"} sx={{margin: 1}}>保存</Button>
            </Box>
        </FormGroup>
    </Paper>
);
```

Comment: Perhaps try use the [`<CssBaseline />`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/) MUI recommended CSS normalize to see if it might improve anything?

Comment: Sorry, It is useless. It only changes the background color.

Comment: What would you like it to do? Ignore the pre-existing CSS in the page?

Comment: Yes, the per-existing CSS is inserted by load-style.php.